# PDF to XML and back to PDF again

Tags: xml, pdf

Well I recently asked a question about getting a PDF-file to become an XML-file and then return it to a PDF-file preferably exactly the same as the original, but at least almost the same.

I've been trying different methods and so far I came up with this one.

1. The document written in LibreOffice gets saved as DocBook XML. Say it's named "file.xml".
2. This file is parsed with a set of XSL templates from the DocBook-project initiated by the file "docbook.xsl".
3. This gets done by running: xsltproc -o intermediate-fo-file.fo /usr/share/xml/docbook/stylesheet/nwalsh/fo/docbook.xsl file.xml
4. The result is an intermediate XSL-FO which becomes a PDF by running: fop intermediate-fo-file.fo final.pdf
5. This PDF-file looks almost the same as the original ODT-file.

But still, say I have a PDF-file in the beginning, how could the same thing be done? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

The only chance of a lossless conversion from PDF to XML is to use a target XML vocabulary which has the same view of documents that PDF has.  Since PDF's view of documents is focused primarily if not exclusively on presentation, and the usual motivation for the design of XML vocabularies like Docbook is to capture higher-level abstractions, you face two difficulties:  (1) presentation-oriented XML vocabularies are not thick on the ground, and (2) if you want to go from PDF to a more conventional XML vocabulary (either directly or via a presentation-oriented XML) you will be pushing water uphill, trying to interpret the presentation of the document in terms of the higher-level abstractions of your target vocabulary.  It will be very difficult, at best, to automate such a process.

If this is a kind of thought experiment and you are thinking about the PDF-XML-PDF round trip to see when and how it's possible, then you now know the reasons some people will give for believing it's not possible in any general form.  If you want this PDF-to-PDF data flow for some practical reason, you might want to reflect on whether your practical goals can be met in some other way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Gradually I've come to understand the difficulty in doing this task but still given the huge benefits in would accomplish given the fraction of space an XML requires in comparison with the same info presented in PDF. In some cases it's tenfold - XML=10kb PDF=1Mb In huge long term archiving systems where we handle milions of documents it's would make an impact if the files could be stored in XML, but presented in PDF - given the common situation that companies and authorities originally produce a huge proportion of documents in PDF to start with.

Comment: @Paul if your pdf documents are simple I'm fairly sure you can do what you originally asked. also, have you had a look at PDF/A (PDF for archiving)?

Comment: Hi Jimmy! Well PDF/A-1 and PDF/A-2 are well suited formats for long term archiving but rather bulky in comparison with XML.

Comment: @PaulBergström: What Xml format are you comparing to PDF? DocBook? In that case, the assumption that the Xml format is an adequate yet space-saving representation of the PDF is limited to PDFs generated from DocBOok Xmls; it doesn't necessarily hold for any other PDFs produced by any companies or authorities.

Answer (score 1):

If your documents are in any way like full-text articles (e.g. http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk/example.pdf), [PDFX](http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk/) might be able to help.

It converts PDF articles to XML similar in structure to Docbook documents. It also tries to retain some positioning information about the extracted elements as they were found in the original PDF (e.g. page & column numbers) that could help you go from PDFX XML to the Docbook XML you already make PDFs out of.

Example input/output: http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk/example

Usage: http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk/usage

You might also consider the Tex alternative to XSL-FO, [TeXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeXML). I had an old XSL to turn PDFX-like XML into .texml, then `texml` could turn it into `.tex`.

(Disclosure: I wrote PDFX.)

Comment: Why don't you tell us about the API you used ? We are developers here.

Comment: Link is no longer responding as of Dec 2015.

Comment: @StephaneRolland I appreciate it's been ages, but -- PDFX only uses a PDF library to get at pages, words and images & figures out the logical structure through statistics, dependency rules & typesetting. A short description of the mechanism is referenced on the PDFX homepage: http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2494266.2494271