# how to get xsl from existing pdf?

Tags: xslt, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Is it possible to get the .xsl file from an existing .pdf file?

I know that with Apache FOP you can get a .pdf file from a .xml and .xsl but I would like to go in the other direction. Any idea?

```
XML+XSL->PDF with Apache FOP, but is it somehow possible PDF->XSL?????
```

The reason why I would like to do that is because I want to open a PDF that has a form inside, edit it adding some information to the form and then save it again as PDF.

I already have the edited form as .xml and I'm trying to generate the PDF, but the I need a .xsl file for the layout... so I thought that maybe I could reuse the layout from the original PDF as they will be the same. Any other better approach?? I would like to avoid creating a specific XSL file for every form.

Thanks

Comment: When converting an Xml file to PDF, a lot information related to presentation of the file is added, while other information, related to the abstract structure of the document, maybe left out. In particular, PDF files created in any other way (e.g. from a vector graphics application, or simply with a different XSLT than the one you're using) may not be suitable for representation with the Xml format you intend to use at all. See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126282/pdf-to-xml-and-back-to-pdf-again/12126750) for more information on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not the XSLT file, since that's not even part of what FOP does. FOP only works with FO documents, the fact that it allows you to use XML+XSLT to get the FO source is just a nice usability feature. However, once it gets the FO file, it doesn't know how that was obtained, so it can't embed in any way the XSLT file.

You could post-process the PDF file using another tool, like PDFBox, to embed any metadata you want.