# Java creating PDF file

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xslt

I am currently working at a project which generates contracts. The idea is that I put the data in a form and save it in a simple database.
So long, this was my favorite place to search for good ideas and simple solutions.

Now I am facing another problem and I don't know how I can solve that. I want to create a PDF and replace some placeholders with some data from my form.
One idea was, that I use an existing Word template with some bookmarks and replace them with the data from my form. Maybe there is a way to do that, and I am just too stupid to find it.

Another idea was, that I am using XML. Therefore, I thought I was clever and just converted the Word template to an PDF, so I am able to convert that PDF to an XML. Attached, you find the XML file. But now I need the XSL file - is there an easy way to create the XSL file?

Or maybe there is another simple solution to solve my problem.

In these [attachments](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApxzaO3-cFXEiOAHy8C1STJleaF4lw?e=bjmMjS) you find the PDF file, the Word template and the XML:

Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200183/how-to-get-xsl-from-existing-pdf

Comment: I have used [XMLtoPDF](http://xml-2-pdf.sourceforge.net/phpdoc/html/Xml2Pdf/tutorial_Xml2Pdf.pkg.html) for PHP -- I wonder if there is a JAVA equivalent ..

Comment: The normal route is to use XSLT to convert the XML to XSL-FO, and then use an library such as FOP or AntennaHouse to convert XSL-FO to PDF.

Comment: You mentioned XSL and XLS.  Which is it?

Comment: @PaulJowett you are right, sorry for that typo. I mean XSL - I will edit my post.

Comment: @MichaelKay thanks for your quick response.
To convert the XML file I need a XSL file I guess?

Comment: Yes, this route involves writing XSLT code. It's the approach that gives you most control over what you're producing, but there may be simpler approaches especially if it doesn't need to be highly automated or efficient - you don't say anything about volumes.

Answer (score 0):

Using a template is a good idea - it makes some changes much quicker to make and then deploy.  The comments above are focused on conversion, but don't forget you need to merge your data in (population) first.

If you can use Adobe tools, you can have a PDF template and use the Adobe tools to populate.  This saves a "conversion" stage.

You mentioned using Word for templates.  This means you to run through two stages of processing:

1. population - docx is a zipped set of XML files - so you can process them with your own code or using a library.
2. conversion - you need pdf, so you have to convert the docx to pdf.  You also have to watch out for fonts at this stage (ie make sure they are available on your host).

The population stage you could do yourself since you are familiar with XML.  But it is definitely complicated.  The conversion needs to use a tool that is ideal for it.  There are a few mentioned in the comments already.

There are some free/os and commercial tools that can do both parts:

- docx4j
- JOD Reports
- Libre Office (using the Java Uno API) (I blogged this once - [Java Convert Word to PDF with UNO](https://www.docmosis.com/company/blog/7-february-2015.html))
- Docmosis (please note I work for Docmosis)

I suggest starting with the simple example you have attached and prove you can both populate and convert that.  Then switch to a more complicated example to see if you can do the other things that might be required (eg repeating or conditions or other logic) during the population stage.